# PhalconPHP - Scanning error before .. when parsing error

Tags: php, mysql, phalcon

I'm building a web application with `PhalconPHP 1.3.4`, I'm trying to select data from multiple tables at the same time, as certain values are stored in another table via relationships.

My query works fine in MySQL workbench, however when I try to execute it with PhalconPHP, i get the following error:

```
Scanning error before 'Bookings, Trips]...' when parsing: SELECT count(bkId) AS bookings FROM [Bookings, Trips] WHERE ((bkUserId = :userId:) AND (CURDATE() > tripFromDate)) AND (CURDATE() < DATE_ADD(tripFromDate, INTERVAL 2 WEEK)) (172)
```

My PHP code:

```
$query = new Builder();
$query->columns("count(bkId) AS bookings");
$query->from('Bookings, Trips');
$query->where("bkUserId = :userId:");
$query->andWhere("CURDATE() > tripFromDate");
$query->andWhere("CURDATE() < DATE_ADD(tripFromDate, INTERVAL 2 WEEK)");
$result = $query->getQuery()->execute(["userId" => $userId])->bookings;
return ($result > 0);
```

I've read that this could be a bug, however it should have been fixed in version 1.3.2, is there something I am currently doing wrong?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe two columns in the from is the proper syntax. In the documentation there is this example:

```
$builder->from('Robots')
    ->addFrom('Parts', 'p');
```

So your example should be something like

```
 $query = new Builder();
    $query->columns("count(b.bkId) AS bookings");
    $query->from('Bookings', 'b');
    $query->addFrom('Trips');
    $query->where("b.bkUserId = :userId:");
    $query->andWhere("CURDATE() > b.tripFromDate");
    $query->andWhere("CURDATE() < DATE_ADD(b.tripFromDate, INTERVAL 2 WEEK)");
```

Either this or you're probably better off converting to use a join.